# The meaning of "a balance is struck at intervals"

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to this [link](http://www.teachmefinance.com/Financial_Terms/Deposit_book.html#google_vignette), "a deposit book is the book held by a depositor in a bank in which are entered the sums placed to his credit and in which, when a balance is struck at intervals, the amount of the debits also is entered." Could someone help me understand the meaning of "a balance is struck at intervals" in this context?

I did a search and "[strike price intervals](http://www.kotaksecurities.com/mailer/derivaemchapter3/strike_prizes.html#:~:text=Strike%20Price%20Intervals%20are%20the,each%20Index%20and%20Stock%20Options.&text=Although%20the%20intervals%20are%20fixed,the%20change%20in%20spot%20prices.)" was what I found, but I don't think one thing has to do with another in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The expression is:

***[strike a balance](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/strike+a+balance)*** (in the financial sense)

> Find a compromise, as in We have to strike a balance between what we want and what we can afford. ***This expression alludes to accounting, where it signifies finding a profit or loss by weighing income versus outlay***. [Mid-1800s]

(AHD)

When *balance is struck at intervals* that is *when you calculate the balance between debits and credits* at intervals, that is every 1, 3 or 6 months for instance.